# Реализация сжатия DEFLATE

Tags: алгоритм, сжатие, deflate

Добрый день. В рамках лабораторной работы собираюсь реализовать алгоритм сжатия deflate. Читаю спецификацию, но пока не понял: как в выходном потоке (промежуточном) должна выглядеть последовательность, сжатая по Хаффману? Сначала храним дерево Хэмминга, потом данные? В каком формате хранить дерево Хаффмана?

В спецификации написано:

> Каждый блок состоит из двух частей: пара Huffman деревьев, которые описывают представление сжатых данных, и сжатые данные. (Сами деревья Huffman сжимаются используя Huffman кодирование.)

Почему пара деревьев, какое дерево к каким данным относится? Если сами деревья тоже сжимать Хаффманом, получается нужно выводить в поток деревья для сжатых деревьев?

> Деревья кода для каждого блока записываются в компактной форме перед сжатыми данными этого блока.

Что значит "в компактной форме"?